# Crear consulta en SQL para calcular un precio

Tags: sql

Quisiera hacer una consulta que me retorne el costo total de una receta.

> Mis tablas son:

**Viandas**

- ID
- Nombre
- ID_Cliente
- Costo (Este campo se completa cuando creo una nueva receta, donde se calcula su precio, pero la idea seria hacer la consulta que planteo en esta pregunta, y eliminar este campo)

**Igredientes**

- ID
- Nombre
- Unidad_de_Medida
- Precio

**Vianda-Ingredientes**

- ID_Ingrediente
- ID_Vianda
- Cantidad

  ---

Como pueden ver, la ultima tabla es la que relaciona a ambas. Yo quisiera obtener el costo de la vianda, que seria, primero obtener el ID de dicha vianda, ir a la tabla `vianda-ingredientes` y recoger todos los elementos que tengan `id=id_vianda`. Ahora tengo todos los Ingredientes (sus ID) que forman la receta, con sus cantidades. Tengo que ir ahora con cada uno de estos ingredientes a la tabla en cuestion, a verificar su precio. Y tengo que multiplicar cantidad*precio de ingrediente, (seria una multiplicacion por cada ingrediente que integre la receta) e ir sumando estas operaciones.

Yo lo hice con JAVASCRIPT para el front-end, y asi lo guardo originalmente en la base de datos. Esto funciona perfecto, pero el problema vino cuando quise meter un trigger que actualice mis precios de menu al actualizar un precio de un ingrediente.

Entonces estoy pensando hacer caso a lo que me dijeron los yankees, y borrar este valor de mi base de datos y calcularlo cada vez que sea necesario. De esta manera no voy a necesitar dicho trigger.

La cosa es que en JS pude hacerlo, pero con SqL soy bastante queso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres calcular el costo al vuelo, lo puedes hacer en la misma consulta de esta forma.

```
SELECT v.ID,
    v.Nombre,
    Costo = SUM(vi.Cantidad * i.Precio)
FROM Viandas v
JOIN [Vianda-Ingredientes] vi ON v.ID = vi.ID_Vianda
JOIN Ingredientes i ON vi.ID_Ingrediente = i.ID
GROUP BY v.ID, v.Nombre;
```

Si quieres actualizar todos los costos para que no tengas que calcularlos cada vez (algo que no es necesario y se debe cuidar de actualizar los datos automáticamente) puedes hacer de la siguiente manera (en SQL Server)

```
UPDATE v SET
    Costo = c.Costo
FROM Viandas v
CROSS APPLY( SELECT SUM(vi.Cantidad * i.Precio) AS Costo
            FROM [Vianda-Ingredientes] vi
            JOIN Ingredientes i ON vi.ID_Ingrediente = i.ID
            WHERE v.ID = vi.ID_Vianda)c;
```

No es necesario ningún foreach o varias llamadas a la base de datos que solo agregan tráfico en la red.